# Cropped Screenshot is Blank - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot, fullscreen, crop

I used this Swift code to crop a screenshot:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width * 0.25, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width * 0.25), false, 0);
    self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width * 0.5,UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height * 0.5,view.bounds.size.width,view.bounds.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
    var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

However, the screenshot is coming up all white. What is my problem?

Comment: Are you sure that at this point in your code, `self.view` is not just white? Have its subviews been initialized? Try setting a breakpoint at these lines and running this command in the debugger: `po [self.view recursiveDescription]`.